# How to write SQL Server query in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have `Process` SQL Server table and some columns and their values.

```
              ID                      Step StateID  SenderNo                
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    9   125     1750069133      
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    8   120     1111111162  
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    5   116     1111111162      
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    2   115     3900383669      
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    1   113     1750069133      
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    9   125     1750069133  
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    8   120     1111111162  
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    5   116     1111111162  
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    2   115     3900383669  
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    1   113     1750069133  
21456qwf-674s-75df-53sg-125sdfsgsd47    5   116     1111111162  
21456qwf-674s-75df-53sg-125sdfsgsd47    2   115     3900383669  
21456qwf-674s-75df-53sg-125sdfsgsd47    1   113     1750069133
```

I want to get data according to highest `Step` value. Like that;

```
 ID                                  Step StateID   SenderNo                
61cc2608-81b8-48a2-89ce-8887438985bb    9   125     1750069133
14dsfgd4-123d-21ds-86ds-124sgslkgj31    9   125     1750069133
21456qwf-674s-75df-53sg-125sdfsgsd47    5   116     1111111162
```

I have no idea how to write the necessary T-SQL query in ASP.Net (C#)...

Comment: How are those the highest `Step`? I see rows with `8`... can you clarify? Or do you mean the highest step per ID?

Comment: You can use ADO.NET component or LinqToSql. Try to see this technet guide: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/934.how-to-use-asp-net-with-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Use this post, http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/, and execute that code server-side in the appropriate event. There are many other ways of getting at the data, and I **prefer** `Dapper`, but this is a start.

Comment: The highest step for a given ID?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, it means highest step of per ID

Comment: and you want help with the SQL statement?

Comment: @Fred yes,plesae. I cannot create SQL statement for this event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is to write the TSQL that you need. By my reckoning, that is:

```
select ID, Step, StateID, SenderNo
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by ID order by Step desc) as [_row]
    from Process) x where x.[_row]=1
```

Next, you need to talk to the server in code. I'm going to use ["dapper"](http://www.nuget.org/packages/dapper) for convenience:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var rows = conn.Query<Process>(@"
select ID, Step, StateID, SenderNo
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by ID order by Step desc) as [_row]
    from Process) x where x.[_row]=1").ToList();

    // ... use rows
}
```

where `Process` is a class you define with suitable `ID`, `Step`, `StateID`, `SenderNo` properties. Or you can avoid that via `dynamic`:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var rows = conn.Query(@"
select ID, Step, StateID, SenderNo
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by ID order by Step desc) as [_row]
    from Process) x where x.[_row]=1").ToList();

    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.ID); // dynamic member resolution
        Console.WriteLine(row.Step);
        //...             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of examples on the web showing how to query a database in ASP.NET but the query you want would be along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY step DESC) 
    FROM tbl
) t
WHERE rn=1
```